# ActionController::UnknownFormat in Rails production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display a flash message when I clicked the "check" button without re-rendering the entire page.

**In the development mode, the code below does work but doesn't in the production mode.** 
Instead of staying in the main.html and displaying the flash message, it redirect me to "check" page.

The log console gave me debug messages below:

> Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
>   app/controllers/my_controller.rb:105:in `check'

Did I miss something for working on production mode?

**main.html.erb**

```
<div class="check"><%= render partial: 'check' %></div>
<%= f.submit :Check, class: "btn btn-default", remote: true, formaction: app_check_path %>
```

**_check.html.erb**

```
<div id = "notice">
</div>
```

**check.js.erb**

```
$("#notice").html('<p style="color: green;"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>').show().delay(5000).hide(0);
```

**my_controller.rb**

```
def check
   notice = "NOTICE!"
   respond_to do |format|
       format.js do
          flash[:notice] = notice
       end
   end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'app/check'
post 'app/check'
```

Comment: Check the server if you the form is being submitted in js format. You can put the server log of the request cycle.

Comment: @Rubyrider Okay, you gave me the idea. I manage to solve this issue by adding (:format => :js) in app_check_path then it's worked.

Comment: Glad to know that it works! Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

**_check.html.erb**

```
<% flash.each do |msg| %>
    <%= msg.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

**check.js.erb**

```
$("#notice").html('<%= escape_javascript(render("check")) %>');
```

**my_controller.rb**

Change this line

```
notice = "<p style='color: green;'>NOTICE!</p>"
```

Hope to help

Comment: I think the problem is not about syntax. As I mention "In the development mode, the code below does work but doesn't in the production mode"

When I submit some data with remote: true, the controller do its work successfully in development mode. I mean, it called only the js without rendering the entire page (calling html) or redirect to any new target page.

But come to the production mode, It showed "Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2ms " which means it's requesting for the html file and redirecting to the target page (action) and then lead me to the error page.

Comment: @boated_tw I have shared which I have implemented and it's working properly with my app

Comment: Thanks for you sharing.
After I tried to apply your implementation, It showed me this "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `html_safe' for ["notice", "<p style='color: green;'>NOTICE!</p>"]:Array)".

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your form in JS format in order to render a JS type response!